# How to create a correct sequence for a bill?

Tags: database, postgresql, web-applications

I'm developing a web application for a drugstore.
This application needs to generate bills for customers. So my question is this:

How I can do for do correctly my database (PostgreSQL 9.5)?
I can't use increment because I can't lose any register.
For example: A001 - A002 - A003 ...
So If I use increment in any moment I can lose the sequence and that can't be happen.

What I can do for solve this?

Thanks for your help.

(Sorry for my english grammar I'm learning it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for increment the value in given sequence.

```
SELECT 'A'||lpad((regexp_replace('A001', '\D','','g')::numeric+1)::text,3,'0') AS result
```

So if value is A001, above will give A002. in place of 'A001', you can put the column name having sequences.